# Use of Article before Nation name

Tags: articles, definite-article

> **Everywhere the local turks vowed that death was preferable to rule by Greeks.**

Except in this line, everywhere in the text the author used ***the Greeks***. Why is *the* not used before "Greeks" in the above sentence? Is there any exception or any other rule that governs it?

Comment: In this case, the omission of the article was merely a stylistic choice on the part of the author. No, there is no "rule" governing when the article must or must not be used as a determiner with a national or ethnic "label".

Comment: @P.E.Dant..we could call it an exception?

Comment: It's not an exception, no. The author could as easily have written _"...preferable to rule by the Greeks"_ with no change in meaning.

Answer (score 4):

> death was preferable to rule by Greeks
>
> death was preferable to rule by the Greeks

It can depend on context - these phrases *might* mean the same thing.

If the writer previously referred to a particular *group* of people who happen to be Greek, *"**the** Greeks"* would be referring to that particular group.

In your sentence it is fairly clear that **any** and **all** Greeks (not just one particular group) are being referred to.